# Laravel ORM - Custom GroupBy Month JSON Response

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I currently I have a model like this-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserSlidePhoto extends Model
{
    protected $table="users_slides_photos";
    protected $fillable=['user_id','social_image_id','original_image_name','provider_key','provider_id','thumbnail_name'];

    public $timestamps = true;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

And a controller like this-

```
public  function rearrangePhotoMonth(Request $request)
{
    //$ordering = $request->input('ordering');
    $thumbs = url('/uploads/userfiles/thumbs/')."/";
    $images = url('/uploads/userfiles/images/')."/";

    return UserSlidePhoto::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                  ->selectRaw(
                                "
                                DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%M, %Y') as month,
                                id,
                                CONCAT('".$thumbs."',thumbnail_name) AS thumbnail_url,
                                CONCAT('".$images."',original_image_name) AS original_image_url"
                              )
                  ->groupBy('month')
                  ->orderBy('month', 'desc')
                  ->get();
}
```

And I am getting JSON response like this-

```
[
  {
    "month": "November, 2019",
    "id": 7,
    "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-aZa54HnAqwY2DPMlSVI2UpbRohVTlY.png",
    "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-aZa54HnAqwY2DPMlSVI2UpbRohVTlY.png"
  },
  {
    "month": "November, 2017",
    "id": 1,
    "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-Xfvn6b8rnE4loZjZOlv14c0FZYVT3A.png",
    "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-Xfvn6b8rnE4loZjZOlv14c0FZYVT3A.png"
  },
  {
    "month": "November, 2016",
    "id": 4,
    "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-A7rlDeFmMybmXNUtcxKyEtzM9TPywq.png",
    "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-A7rlDeFmMybmXNUtcxKyEtzM9TPywq.png"
  },
  {
    "month": "November, 2011",
    "id": 3,
    "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-NfMq71wghF7Al3Fn4KS3SG9ylC4ayo.png",
    "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-NfMq71wghF7Al3Fn4KS3SG9ylC4ayo.png"
  },
  {
    "month": "November, 2009",
    "id": 5,
    "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-r6jxeFfV7nnLrMxO5l88sC7Pt0Xq1A.png",
    "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-r6jxeFfV7nnLrMxO5l88sC7Pt0Xq1A.png"
  },
  {
    "month": "November, 2008",
    "id": 9,
    "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-ivnXQ5ZA1y2mVVxcRtmH3UFd41Xdg3.png",
    "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-ivnXQ5ZA1y2mVVxcRtmH3UFd41Xdg3.png"
  },
  {
    "month": "March, 1996",
    "id": 2,
    "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-YgLYcr5DsB3kHjpa7cxcznjiEFdzeF.png",
    "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-YgLYcr5DsB3kHjpa7cxcznjiEFdzeF.png"
  }
]
```

But I like to get response like this-

```
[
  {
    "month": "January 2015",
    "data": {
      {
        "id": 6,
        "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-WujsXF8iNSuwxQX4QRebKkOqFinlJV.png",
        "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-WujsXF8iNSuwxQX4QRebKkOqFinlJV.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-VcgQcjoi0iXM2YOqhgt0fYUZf8kwsE.png",
        "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-VcgQcjoi0iXM2YOqhgt0fYUZf8kwsE.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-r6jxeFfV7nnLrMxO5l88sC7Pt0Xq1A.png",
        "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-r6jxeFfV7nnLrMxO5l88sC7Pt0Xq1A.png"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "month": "March 2015",
    "data": {
      {
        "id": 2,
        "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-YgLYcr5DsB3kHjpa7cxcznjiEFdzeF.png",
        "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-YgLYcr5DsB3kHjpa7cxcznjiEFdzeF.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-ivnXQ5ZA1y2mVVxcRtmH3UFd41Xdg3.png",
        "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-ivnXQ5ZA1y2mVVxcRtmH3UFd41Xdg3.png"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "month": "January 2016",
    "data": {
      {
        "id": 3,
        "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/thumbs\/2-NfMq71wghF7Al3Fn4KS3SG9ylC4ayo.png",
        "original_image_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/uploads\/userfiles\/images\/2-NfMq71wghF7Al3Fn4KS3SG9ylC4ayo.png"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it like this way-

```
public  function rearrangePhotoMonth(Request $request)
{
    //$ordering = $request->input('ordering');
    $thumbs = url('/uploads/userfiles/thumbs/')."/";
    $images = url('/uploads/userfiles/images/')."/";

    $collection = UserSlidePhoto::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                  ->selectRaw(
                                "
                                DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%M, %Y') as month,
                                id,
                                CONCAT('".$thumbs."',thumbnail_name) AS thumbnail_url,
                                CONCAT('".$images."',original_image_name) AS original_image_url"
                              )
                  ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                  ->get();

    return collect($collection)
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->all();
}
```

It is working now :).

Answer (score 1):

You have bad query, just run it to see that it return only one row per each month.

So you need to remove **group_by** clause and do it manually in PHP or use [laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-groupby)

Answer (score 0):

A `group by` will only give you one row per month.

Unless there is some eloquent magic I don't know yet (Which is quite probably true), you'll have to parse the array via PHP to organize your data.